# will show NSObject show UIActivityIndicatorView?

Tags: iphone

i use NSobject class inwhich i have NSURLConnection,but how can i show UIActivityIndicatorView when connection established and finished.....?i tried
in appdelegate.m file inwhich i have mentioned in appdidfnish method

```
    Search = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]  
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
     [Search setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)]; 
     [window addSubview: Search];
```

and also i have individual method like

```
      -(void)anim
{
   [search startAnimating];
}
```

but if i call this method through appdelegate object in NSobject.m page, it will not work..
what i have to do? any help? please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but where are you setting the frame of your activityIndicatorView? I've just tried this piece of code and it works perfect.

> ```
>   activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
>  [activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
>  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
> [window addSubview:activityIndicator];
> UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
> [button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 120, 50)];
> [button setTitle:@"press me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onBtnClk) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
> [window addSubview:button];
> [window makeKeyAndVisible];
> ```

and this is onBtnClk method

> ```
> - (void) onBtnClk{
> if([activityIndicator isAnimating]){
>  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
> }else{
>  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: normally if we declare like following it works in view controller...
Search = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]  
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
     [Search setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)]; 
     [window addSubview: Search];
-(void)anim
{
   [search startAnimating];
}

Comment: but i cannot stop in other methods like [activityIndicator startAnimating];

because it is declared as local variable